# <bsd/string.h> not found under MacOS

Tags: c, macos

For a project I need to include `<bsd/string.h>`.

Unfortunately this does not come preinstalled on a Mac. I have learned that it is in the `libbsd-dev` package, but that library is not included in brew (my package manager of choice).

What other ways are there to get that library? Googling brought me to this:

**repo**: https://github.com/JackieXie168/libbsd

but I am not able to install that. Would installing that package already be enough?

I am using the most up to date brew and macOS 10.12.4.

Comment: Are you certain that you can't just use `<string.h>`? OS X is a BSD derivative.

Comment: @larsks that fixed it. Error was somewhere else